# Ensuring immutability of the original when setting and deleting from a map object

Tags: javascript

I've been studying how to accomplish immutability/functional programming in JavaScript and I am having difficulties with the following code. The object returned from the `generateExample` function contains methods to add and remove keys/values from a map, by iterating over an array of objects.

Scenario 1 simply uses the map methods `set` and `delete` methods and mutates the map. Scenario 2 creates a new map prior to `setting` and `deleting` keys/values.

I could clone the map for each new `set`, in each `foreach` loop, but I'd imagine that would be too computationally expensive.

I could also use Immutable.js (Map) and have a new data structure returned for each `set` and `delete`. I don't really want to do this.

The object returned from `generateExample` in this example would be the only object that that could `set` and `delete` to the map, so perhaps worrying about immutability in this is an example is not important?

What I am trying to understand is what is the best way to maintain immutability of the original map when setting and deleting keys/values and if it's even relevant?

```
const sampleList = [
  {
    id: 'dog',
    value: 'Dog',
  },
  {
    id: 'cat',
    value: 'Cat',
  },
]
```

**SCENARIO 1**

```
const example = function generateExample() {
  const container = new Map()
  return {
    add(list) {
      list
        .forEach((x) => {
          container.set(x.id, x)
        })
    },
    remove(list) {
      list
        .forEach((x) => {
          container.delete(x.id)
        })
    },
    read(id) {
      return container.get(id)
    },
  }
}
```

**SCENARIO 2**

```
const example = function generateExample() {
  let container = new Map()
  return {
    add(list) {
      container = new Map(container)
      list
        .forEach((x) => {
          container.set(x.id, x)
        })
    },
    remove(list) {
      container = new Map(container)
      list
        .forEach((x) => {
          container.delete(x.id)
        })
    },
    read(id) {
      return container.get(id)
    },
  }
}

const test = example()
test.add(sampleList)
console.log(test.read('dog'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you have mutations. In the first scenario the mutation is over `Map` object, in the second scenario the mutation is over container value itself then again on `Map` object.I'll suggest not to have this layer but just treating the `Map` objects as they are, but if the case must be like this, I'll prefer to do something like this

```
const example = function generateExample(defaultList) {
  let container = new Map(defaultList)
  return {
    add(list) {
      container = new Map(container.concat(list));
    },
    remove(list) {
      container = new Map(container.filter(item => !list.includes(item)))
    },
    read(id) {
      return container.get(id)
    },
  }
}
```